# How to make a pandas column out of filenames?

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have N images. I want to create pandas  dataframe, and put all the filenames of images in these colums.How to do it?
I need a column with header
"filename".
a.jpg
b.jpg

Comment: Please provide more detail in your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add a sample data and expected output in your question by providing proper example

Answer (score 0):

Make an array, where you append filenames.

```
array = []
```

Then save these filenames into pandas.DataFrame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=False, columns=["filenames"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
# fetch all images from your directory 
# I am assuming .png is the extension of images 
file_names = glob.glob('./*.png') # it will give list of file_names ['a.png','b.png']

#if absolute path is like ["C://abc/img.png","C://abc//img2.png]
images = [i.split("/")[-1]for i in file_names]

#if absolute path is like ["C:\\abc\img.png","C:\\abc\\img2.png]
images = [i.split("\\")[-1]for i in file_names]



df = pd.DataFrame(images,columns=['column_name'])
print(df)
```

```
  column_name
0   a.png
1   b.png
```

Comment: Dear tawab, thank you.I put                                                                                    file_names = glob.glob('/home/nis/Downloads/trialdata/testset/test-set/*.jpg')   and the output is whole path location and filename. How to print only filename with its extension.